# Using Maven WAR Plugin with Profiles

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

I'm trying to get images to my Maven web-application according to the profile selected at build time. But I keep on getting the whole folder of all the profiles to the point where I need the images to go.

```
<build>
    <finalName>user-interface</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>src/main/profile/webapp/</directory>
                        <targetPath>images</targetPath>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>user</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

How to fix this? Default image is `banner.jpg` and both profiles have respective images in correct order. Inside `src/main/profile/webapp/` there are 2 folders `user` and `dev` with each having images folder and the `banner.jpg` inside images folder.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a custom property inside each profile and then reference that property in the configuration of the plugin:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>user-interface</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>src/main/profile/webapp/${banner.folder}</directory>
                        <targetPath>images</targetPath>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>user</id>
        <properties>
            <banner.folder>user</banner.folder> <!-- defines banner.folder property when the user profile is activated -->
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <banner.folder>dev</banner.folder> <!-- defines banner.folder property when the dev profile is activated -->
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked fine. Can you also explain why you can't get the id as the identifier rather than a property?

Comment: Because you can have more than one active profile. In fact, the active profiles are a list property.